# Kendo grid jquery: How can I ensure that key press events move the selected row up/down and keep that new selected row viewable?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, grid

Lets say I have a kendo jquery grid with 1000 records, 100 records per page, 25 rows on display for the user given the current size of the grid, rows 26 through 50 currently visible to the user...

If row 25, the top row visible to the user, is selected and the user presses the up button I want row 24 selected and have the viewable selection of records to now be rows 24-49.

Assuming rows 26-50 are displayed and if row 50, the last row visible to the user, is selected and the user presses the down button I want row 51 to be selected and have the viewable selection of records to not be rows 27-51.

And finally, assuming rows 26-50 are displayed and if row 40 is selected and the use presses the up arrow I want row 39 to be selected but I do not want the viewable rows to change. It should remain 26-50.

I can do the whole switching to the previous or next row just fine. It is the changing of the viewable rows only when the selected row was previously not viewable that I cannot figure out.

Here is my code as it currently is set up. Please note that the code as it is now will always attempt to move the selected row to the 4th record from the top.

```
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [{
        field: "Time",
        title: "@(Model.Time)"
    }],
dataSource: {
    serverPaging: false,
},
reorderable: false,
resizable: true,
scrollable: true,
pageable: {
    pageSize: 100,
    pageSizes: true,
    pageSizes: [50, 100, 200, 500, 1000],
    buttonCount: 5,
    messages: {
        display: "{0} - {1} of {2} rows",
        empty: "No items to display",
        page: "Page",
        of: "of {0}",
        itemsPerPage: "rows per page",
        first: "Go to the first page",
        previous: "Go to the previous page",
        next: "Go to the next page",
        last: "Go to the last page",
        refresh: "Refresh"
    }
},
resizable: true,
change: function (e) {
    scrollToSelectedGridPosition();
    settingGridPosition = false;
},
selectable: "row"
});

var gridOfData = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

function scrollToSelectedGridPosition() {
    var scrollContentOffset = gridOfData.element.find("tbody").offset().top;
    var indexOfSelectedRow = gridOfData.select().index();
    var distance = 0;
    if (indexOfSelectedRow >= 3) {
        var fourthOffset = gridOfData.table.find("tr[data-uid=" + gridOfData.dataSource.view()[indexOfSelectedRow - 3].uid + "]").offset().top
        distance = fourthOffset - scrollContentOffset;
    }

    gridOfData.element.find(".k-grid-content").animate({
        scrollTop: distance
    }, 400);

}

$( document ).keyup( function ( event ) {
    if (!isWindowPopupOpen) {
        if (gridVisible == false) {
            //some other unrelated things
        }
        else {
            switch (event.which) {
                case 38: //38 = up
                case 40: //40 = down
                    moveGridSelection(event.which);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
});

function moveGridSelection(eventWhich) {
    if (gridOfData.select().index() == -1) {
        return;
    }
    var currentEventTimeTicks = gridOfData.dataSource.view()[gridOfData.select().index()].EventTimeTicks;
    var data = gridOfData.dataSource.options.data.map(x => x.EventTimeTicks);
    var index = data.indexOf(currentEventTimeTicks);

    if (eventWhich == 38) {
        if (index > 0) {
            changePageIfNecessary(index - 1);
            gridOfData.select(gridOfData.table.find("tr[data-uid=" + gridOfData.dataSource.data()[index - 1].uid + "]"));
        }
    }
    else if (eventWhich == 40) {
        if (index < data.length) {
            changePageIfNecessary(index + 1);
            gridOfData.select(gridOfData.table.find("tr[data-uid=" + gridOfData.dataSource.data()[index + 1].uid + "]"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: share your grid code and keypress functions, please.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes that seem to have addressed the issue. Basically what I wanted to do was have key press events drive both the row selection and scroll the grid. It appears that by default kendo grid does not do that.

I added functionality to find which rows were the top and bottom rows that were in the viewport and compared that to the newly selected row position after a key press event. If the newly selected row was before the top row in the view port then I scrolled to the top based on the position of the newly selected row. If the newly selected was after the bottom row in the view port then I scrolled to the second row in the viewport. If the newly selected row was within the viewport then no scrolling would occur.

The above change worked...sort of. With those changes alone I was left watching the arrow keys move the grid just before my keyup event fired. Which messed with the collection of rows in the viewport resulting in madness.

So I made changes to essentially stop the grid from scrolling based on the arrow keys except for my own custom code.

```
@* Set up the grid *@
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [{
            field: "Time",
            title: "@(Model.EventTime)"
        }],
    dataSource: {
        serverPaging: false,
    },
    reorderable: false,
    resizable: true,
    scrollable: true,
    pageable: {
        pageSize: 100,
        pageSizes: true,
        pageSizes: [50, 100, 200, 500, 1000],
        buttonCount: 5,
        messages: {
            display: "{0} - {1} of {2} rows",
            empty: "No items to display",
            page: "Page",
            of: "of {0}",
            itemsPerPage: "rows per page",
            first: "Go to the first page",
            previous: "Go to the previous page",
            next: "Go to the next page",
            last: "Go to the last page",
            refresh: "Refresh"
        }
    },
    resizable: true,
    change: function (e) {
        if (gridKeyUpOrDown == true) {
            scrollToSelectedGridPosition();
            gridKeyUpOrDown = false;
        }
    },
    selectable: "row",
    autoscroll: false,
});

var gridOfData = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");


function findScrollToTopIndex() {
    if (gridOfData.select().index() == -1) {
        return -1;
    }
    var selectedIndex = gridOfData.select().index();

    var indexOfTopVisibleRow = -1;
    var topVisibileRowTop = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < gridOfData.dataSource.view().length; i++) {
        var row = gridOfData.table.find("tr[data-uid=" + gridOfData.dataSource.view()[i].uid + "]")
        if (row.position() != undefined && row.position().top >= 0) {
            indexOfTopVisibleRow = i;
            topVisibileRowTop = row.position().top;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (indexOfTopVisibleRow == -1) {
        return -1;
    }

    var gridElement = $("#grid"),
        totalHeight = gridElement.innerHeight(),
        otherElements = gridElement.children().not(".k-grid-content"),
        otherElementsHeight = 0;
    otherElements.each(function () {
        otherElementsHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
    });
    var indexOfBottomVisibleRow = -1;
    var contentBottom = (topVisibileRowTop + (totalHeight - otherElementsHeight) - gridOfData.select().innerHeight());
    for (var i = indexOfTopVisibleRow; i < gridOfData.dataSource.view().length; i++) {
        var row = gridOfData.table.find("tr[data-uid=" + gridOfData.dataSource.view()[i].uid + "]")
        if (row.position() != undefined && (row.position().top + row.innerHeight()) > contentBottom) {
            indexOfBottomVisibleRow = i - 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (selectedIndex >= indexOfTopVisibleRow && selectedIndex <= indexOfBottomVisibleRow) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (selectedIndex == (indexOfBottomVisibleRow + 1)) {
        return indexOfTopVisibleRow + 1;
    }
    return selectedIndex;
}


function scrollToSelectedGridPosition() {
    var indexOfSelectedRow = findScrollToTopIndex();
    if (indexOfSelectedRow >= 0) {
        var scrollContentOffset = gridOfData.element.find("tbody").offset().top;
        var offset = gridOfData.table.find("tr[data-uid=" + gridOfData.dataSource.view()[indexOfSelectedRow].uid + "]").offset().top
        var distance = offset - scrollContentOffset;
        gridOfData.element.find(".k-grid-content").scrollTop(distance);
    }
}

$( document ).keyup( function ( event ) {
    if (!isWindowPopupOpen) {
        if (gridVisible == false) {
            //unrelated things
        }
        else {
            switch (event.which) {
                case 38: //38 = up
                case 40: //40 = down
                    moveGridSelection(event.which);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
});

function moveGridSelection(eventWhich) {
    if (gridOfData.select().index() == -1) {
        return;
    }
    var currentEventTimeTicks = gridOfData.dataSource.view()[gridOfData.select().index()].EventTimeTicks;
    var data = gridOfData.dataSource.options.data.map(x => x.EventTimeTicks);
    var index = data.indexOf(currentEventTimeTicks);

    if (eventWhich == 38) {
        if (index > 0) {
            changePageIfNecessary(index - 1);
            gridKeyUpOrDown = true;
            gridOfData.select(gridOfData.table.find("tr[data-uid=" + gridOfData.dataSource.data()[index - 1].uid + "]"));
        }
    }
    else if (eventWhich == 40) {
        if (index < data.length) {
            changePageIfNecessary(index + 1);
            gridKeyUpOrDown = true;
            gridOfData.select(gridOfData.table.find("tr[data-uid=" + gridOfData.dataSource.data()[index + 1].uid + "]"));
        }
    }
}
```

I am sure there must be a better way but it appears to work